# Ingress controller does not allow snippets

Tags: kubernetes-helm, azure-aks, ingress-controller

I'm trying to add a snippet to an existing Ingress that is attached to an ingress-controller.  However, when trying this, i get an error which is:

`for: "app-ingress.yml": error when patching "app-ingress.yml": admission webhook "validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io" denied the request: nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet annotation cannot be used. Snippet directives are disabled by the Ingress administrator`

the ingress already exists and I'm trying to patch it to add a header.  The updated ingress yaml is as follows:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app-web-dev
  namespace: application
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      expires 1M;
      add_header Cache-Control "public";

spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - dev.address.nl
    secretName: app-wildcard
  rules:
  - host: dev.address.nl
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /?(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: appwebsvc
            port:
              number: 80
```

I'm trying to use helm to update my ingress controller to enable snippets, but i can't find the right commands to do this.

Any ideas?

I am trying something like this:

`helm upgrade --namespace ingress-nginx --install --set controller.config.server-snippet=true,controller.service.annotations.nginx\.ingress\.kubernetes\.io/allow-snippet-annotations=true --wait ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx`

Comment: Helm can't patch existing resources; instead, the Helm chart would contain the complete definition of the Ingress and other objects.  Was the Ingress initially created in a Helm chart?  Do you need something like `kubectl patch` instead?

Comment: yes, the ingress was initially created with a helm chart. Ok, maybe i need a kubectl patch instead. But in that case, what would the syntax be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your ingress controller was previously installed using helm chart then you can use helm upgrade.

**Please note that you should do an upgrade if and only if you have access to the exact chart with the same values file which was used to install nginx ingress earlier. You cannot just use a new chart to try to upgrade an existing installation which will cause all the earlier settings to be lost.**

I am assuming your nginx ingress helm chart is

https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/charts/ingress-nginx

the `allowSnippetAnnotations` is the setting which needs to be turned on.

Option 1:
set `allowSnippetAnnotations=true` in values file

Option 2:
try to set setting the value "`--set allowSnippetAnnotations=true`" in your helm upgrade command.

Please share more details on how your nginx ingress controller was installed if you need more help as my answer is on the assumptions I have mentioned above.

Comment: got it Raghu.  Let me try that. Yes, the ingress controller was previously created with a helm chart and I have the exact command used.

Comment: Seems to work. thanks Raghu